# backup compatibility between SQLExpress 2012 and 2016

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server

May I make a backup from SQLExpress 2012 and restore it into a SQLExpress 2016?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The general rule to remember is that backups are like time travel.  You can't go back.

2012 will go to 2016 but a 2016 backup will not restore to 2012.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, a backup created in any version of SQL Server can be restored in later versions.

The reverse is definitely *not* true - a backup taken in SQL Express 2016 could *not* be restored using *any* edition of SQL Server 2012.